# If else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Lately , i have been practicing on my beginner tutorials on java,
However i got stuck with the if else statement ,

My main focus was to let user to write if user try greater than 5 times, it will return false , Else  it will return true.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
int userTry = 0;
double value1 = 0;
Scanner useranswer1 =new Scanner(System.in);

if(userTry == 5){
    do{
        System.out.println("What is 10 divided by 4?");
        value1 = useranswer1.nextDouble();

    }
    while(value1 != 2.5);
    System.out.println("You got the right answer");
    } else  {

    } System.out.println("You have zero more tries"); 
}
```

Comment: You have to put your loop around the if, not the opposite

Comment: Make a loop which allows the person to try up to five times. A `for`-loop seems pretty good for this. If the right answer is yielded (use an `if` to check for this) `break` out of the loop.

Comment: change you while loop to include the number of tries

Comment: Please also post the code you left out. This is not your entire code, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
    int userTry = 0;

    double value1 = 0;
    Scanner useranswer1 =new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int userTry = 5; userTry > 0; userTry--)
        System.out.println("What is 10 divided by 4?");
        value1 = useranswer1.nextDouble();
        if (value1 == 2.5) break;
        System.out.println(); // empty line
    }

    if (value1 == 2.5) {
        System.out.println("You got the right answer");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have zero more tries");
    } 
}
```

Comment: This answer makes more sense than doing a `do-while` loop for no reason

Comment: Could it be that do while loops were the topic of the day, and for loops weren't discussed yet? This looks like a learner's situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int count = 0;
    double trueAnwer = 6.66;
    while (true) {
        count++;
        Scanner useranswer1 =new Scanner(System.in);
        if (trueAnwer == useranswer1.nextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("You got the right answer");
            return;
        }
        if (count==5) {
            System.out.println("You have zero more tries");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("This is "+count+" times");
    }
```

Comment: you don't want to instantiate your `useranswer1` for each iteration of the loop - otherwise good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
do{
    System.out.println("What is 10 divided by 4?");
    value1 = useranswer1.nextDouble();
    userTry++;
}
while(value1 != 2.5 && userTry  != 5);
if(userTry == 5){
        System.out.println("You have zero more tries");    
} else {
    System.out.println("You got the right answer");
}
```

Comment: Jérèm wrong because at the userTry == 4 you'll increment to 5 but he actually got the right answer. But you'll print "You have zero more tries".

Comment: easy to fix isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to set the condition of your do-while loop based on the check that the user didn't get the right value and if they have enough retries.

If the user got the right value, they've done so in the required number of retries, otherwise, they've zero tries. Hope this helps.

```
int userTry = 0;
double value1 = 0.0;
Scanner useranswer1 = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("What is 10 divided by 4?");
    value1 = useranswer1.nextDouble();
} while (value != 2.5 && ++userTry < 5); // NOTE: pre-increment and check. If you like to have a safer version, move this increment inside the while loop.

if (value1 != 2.5) {
    System.out.println("You have zero more tries");
} else {
    System.out.println("You got the right answer!");
}
```